# Let R be the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of all real polynomials. Deﬁne a function θ : R → $\mathbb{C}$ by the rule that fθ= f(i).

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R be the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of all real polynomials. Deﬁne a function θ : R → $\mathbb{C}$ by the rule that fθ= f(i). Prove that θ is a homomorphism, that its image is $\mathbb{C}$, and that its kernel is the ideal $(x^2 + 1)R$ consisting of all polynomials divisible by $x^2 +1$.

Hence show that $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 +1)\mathbb{R}[x] \cong \mathbb{C}.$

I do not know how to approach the problem.Any kind of hints would be helpful.

Comment: Are you having trouble in proving that it is a homomorphism?

Comment: Do you know about the so-called "isomorphism theorems"?

Comment: @Arthur I'm pretty sure that I am supposed  to use the first isomorphism theorem. Which means after I prove it's a homomorphism, I know that the image is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$ and that the kernal is an ideal of R. However, I don't understand how to show more specifically that the image is in fact $\mathbb{C}$ and the kernal is $(x^2+1)R$.

Comment: @SolidSnake I know the definition of a homomorphism, but I'm not sure how to use it. If I were to take a guess, you would show that $(f+g)θ = f(i)θ+g(i)θ and similarly for multiplication. Does that make any sense? My understanding of this material is pretty shaky to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, according to the comments, it seems you know how to prove this is a homomorphism, so let's assume you already did that part.

**1. The kernel is $(x^2 +1)\mathbb{R}[x]$:**

Suppose that some polynomial $f\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ goes to zero under this homomorphism, that is, $\theta(f) = f(i) = 0$, then $i$ is a root of the polynomial $f$ and therefore so is $-i$, the conjugate of $i$ (why?). Hence $(x-i)(x+i) = x^2 + 1$ divides $f$. This shows that every polynomial in the kernel is divisible by $x^2+1$ and therefore the kernel is included in the ideal of multiples of this polynomial, which is $(x^2 +1)\mathbb{R}[x]$. To show that every polynomial in this ideal belongs to the kernel is even easier and I leave that part to you.

**2. The image of $\theta$ is $\mathbb{C}$**

Let $f$ be the constant polynomial $1$ and $g$ the polynomial $x$, then for all $a+bi\in \mathbb{C}$ we have $$\theta(af+bg) = a\theta(f) + b\theta(g) = a+bi$$ so $\theta$ is surjective.